# Angular - Add local external Module to App

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-library

I have a project **my-components** and a project **my-showcase**. **my-components** is an Angular library and **my-showcase** is an Angular app. At time, when I change or add an component in library, I make a commit to private git and publish to private npm. Then I can use it in other apps like **my-showcase**. Before commit and publish I would test it. Until now, I create and develop a new component in my-showcase. After finish, I put it to **my-components**.

At time I import my angular component library over npm:

```
import {TimePickerModule} from '@company/components';
```

For testing and development I change this to local path:

```
import {TimePickerModule} from '../../../../company-components/projects/components/src';
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error message:

```
WARNING in ../company-components/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js 15153:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And:

```
core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DcStickyBitsDirective -> ElementRef]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DcStickyBitsDirective -> ElementRef]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

Apparently the component from the library in app **my-showcase** use the wrong node_module folder from **my-components** (specially @angular/core), not the node_module folder from **my-showcase**.

Does anyone have a solution for me or have I a wrong understanding when dealing with Angular Library and NPM? If it was too incomprehensible, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround. I add following to **tsconfig.json**:

```
"@company/components": [
    "../path/to/projects/components/src"
],

"@angular/*": [
    "node_modules/@angular/*"
]
```

But I don't find this solution very clean. If I understand correctly, the problem is that Webpack takes the Angular stuff from the component library and not from the showcase project. With this workaround, it override the wrong paths.